# how to use HttpClientBuilder in JIRA?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

The Atlassian SDK doesn't like `HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`

ORIGINAL CODE : https://github.com/e-gov/TARA-Java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/intuit/developer/sampleapp/oauth2/controller/CallbackController.java

I need transfer this code to `Jira plugin`

`private static final HttpClient CLIENT = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`

```
private IDTokenResponse requestIDToken(String auth_code, HttpSession session) 
{

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(oAuth2Configuration.getTARATokenEndpoint());

    // Lisa päis
    post = httpHelper.addHeader(post);
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = httpHelper.getUrlParameters(session, "");

    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        HttpResponse response = CLIENT.execute(post);

        logger.info("Response Code : "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            logger.info("Viga identsustõendi pärimisel");
            return null;
        }

        StringBuffer result = httpHelper.getResult(response);
        logger.debug("Identsustõendi päringu vastus: " + result);

        return mapper.readValue(result.toString(), IDTokenResponse.class);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Viga identsustõendi pärimisel", ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What does `Atlassin SDK dont like HttpClientBuilder.create().build();` mean?

Comment: If the problem is that you get some sort of error message and you don't know how to address that, then include the error message etc.  Be precise, accurate and complete.  Just as accurate and complete as you would want users to be toward you when *you* are supposed to solve their problems and all they give you is "my software isn't working".